# Does the .net core built in cookie consent feature block 3rd party cookies automatically?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, cookieconsent

Asp .net core has this built in cookie consent feature where you can get permissions form a user to use cookies which are not marked as essential. I use this in Startup.cs (.net core 3.1) like shown in the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/gdpr?view=aspnetcore-3.1

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });
```

Now my question is: If a user does not give the permission to use cookies, does this automatically prevent cookies from 3parties (like Google analytics, or cookies form embedded youtube videos, and so on..) too? So that no additional work on my side is needed? Or is this feature only useful for my own cookies?

Thank you very much for any help here!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, my own test showed, that this does not prevent the adding of 3rd party cookies

Comment: What was your solution in the end? I am also trying to properly implement Google analytics consent on my app.

Comment: Hi Scribbio, I ended up not using the .net core consent feature. Because there the user can only consent for cookies or not. But in the EU you need more options. It needs to be possible to allow certain cookies but maybe not thrid party cookies.

So now I set my own cookie where I save what cookies are allowd from the website user.

Google Analytics: I use the new version 4, which was just published last month. With the new version it is easy to disable if cookies are not allowed:

See here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/disable-analytics